# Can't install app in AppCatalog

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, error, spfx, provider-hosted-app

Trying to upload an app to a Sharepoint Online App Catalog. Getting the following error:

> xxxxxxxx.app  Unknown Status Module: 33 Message: 134

It worked 4 days ago. The only thing that I have changed in the solution is the version number in the manifest. Starting/debugging the application from visual studio works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is currently some issue going on at Microsoft's end(across most regions) because of which you are not able to install app in App Catalog. This is affecting both SPFx solutions as well as SharePoint addins (Provider-hosted and 
SharePoint-hosted).

Nothing you can do at the moment.

Check your [service health status](https://portal.office.com) -> Health -> Service health ->  SharePoint online advisory (need global admin credentials).

[image]

This is going on since yesterday night I guess. Wait till tomorrow for further update.

Github sp-dev-docs issue - [New issue SPFx package : Upload to app catalog fails](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1318)

Comment: The Cloud will save us all haha. Thanks Gautam, was banging my head

Comment: Looks like this is getting fixed. They have rolled out a fix which will get deployed across all tenants in couple of hours i guess . Started working in our Australian tenants. But not in couple other tenants based in Europe. However, the advisory is still present, so hold your breath.